# Automatically push subtree changes to Azure repository

Tags: git, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, git-subtree

I am using Azure DevOps to work on two projects I'll name `P1` and `P2`. `P1` is a project containing some code I'd like to reuse in `P2`. I'd like to use [subtrees](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-subtree) in order to do that. `P1` will be driving most (if not all) that code so I'd favour a subtree over a submodule. I've setup a third project on Azure I'll call `C` meant to contain that shared code.

```
git-subtree-child (C)
  child.txt

git-subtree-parent-1 (P1)
  azure-pipelines.yml
  git-subtree-child (C)
    child.txt

git-subtree-parent-2 (P2)
  git-subtree-child (C)
    child.txt
```

My git client does not support subtrees. I can't ask my teammates to use the CLI to call `git subtree push ...` every time the shared code is updated (one will forget I'm sure!)

So, I'm setting up an Azure pipeline to push to `C` the code committed from `P1`. But I'm facing difficulties reaching `C`'s git repository, located **in the same organisation**.

---

### Pipeline script

```yaml
trigger:
 branches:
   include:
     - release/*

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

steps:
- checkout: self
  persistCredentials: true

- script: |
    branch=$(Build.SourceBranch)
    branch=${branch/#"refs/heads/"} # Remove "refs/heads/" from the source branch name
    echo $branch
    git subtree split --prefix=git-subtree-child --branch=extract-child-subtree
    git push https://dev.azure.com/<organisation>/GitSubtreeProofOfConcept/_git/git-subtree-child extract-child-subtree:$branch
    git branch --delete --force extract-child-subtree
  displayName: Push subtree to child repo
```

### Job Output:

```
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/6cf48f51-4eb1-4797-9a26-2cb68b904f8d.sh
release/AzurePipeline
1/1 (0) [0]
Created branch 'extract-child-subtree'
f871ba0e0cf7a2ff48c3ed046a2c0eb56cbeed40
fatal: could not read Username for 'https://dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled
Deleted branch extract-child-subtree (was f871ba0).
```

I have the `persistCredentials` flag set to `true` in the `checkout` step, and I gave Contribution permissions as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66470759/set-git-credentials-inside-a-azure-yaml-pipeline) to `GitSubtreeProofOfConcept Build Service` in the **three** projects (`P1`, `P2` and `C`) (`Project Settings → Repositories → <project> → Security`). So it *should* be working from what I see online.

[image: Permissions]

The only way I made it working is by providing an access token by replacing:

`git push https://dev.azure.com/<organisation>/GitSubtreeProofOfConcept/_git/git-subtree-child`

by

`git push https://$(System.AccessToken)@dev.azure.com/<organisation>/GitSubtreeProofOfConcept/_git/git-subtree-child`.

---

Even if I go this way, I still have **ANOTHER** error

```
/usr/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/58591c72-da26-4758-9d24-6270bbc6a1e5.sh
release/AzurePipeline
1/1 (0) [0]
Created branch 'extract-child-subtree'
98b98c18804a186ffa5033c9caa39eaef14fbb6d
remote: TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier git-subtree-child does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are attempting.
fatal: repository 'https://dev.azure.com/<organisation>/GitSubtreeProofOfConcept/_git/git-subtree-child/' not found
Deleted branch extract-child-subtree (was 98b98c1).
```

But as you can see, the repository is present and **has** the branch I'm trying to push to (`release/AzurePipeline`, printed by the job itself).

[image: Repositories]

The `Limit job authorization scope to current project for (non-)release pipelines` flags have been **unchecked** as advised [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63606694/multi-repository-throwing-tf401019-on-checkout)

[image: Settings]

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: The settings  are not correct, see my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description, there are two obvious problems.

**1, Permission assignment error.**

From your screenshot:

[image]

So in this situation, the 'Auth' identity is collection level(Organization level), but you are trying to assign permission to project level:

[image]

You should assign permission to this service account:

[image]

**2，Repositories already been prevent from YAML pipelines' access.**

You have disable the access from YAML pipeline to repositories:

[image]

But you were using YAML pipeline. In this situation, your pipeline will be unable to change the repo.

I notice the color of this setting is grey, you need to go to organization settings to change this.

Comment: Thank you! `Project Collection Build Service` had the authorizations already but after unchecking  `Protect access to repositories in YAML pipelines` from the organisation & project settings, it worked! ‍♂️